# Prolog: list of lists

Tags: prolog

I have a problem on Prolog related to list of lists. The problem is about implementing a Prolog predicate: `to_do(ListOfLists,_,Result)`.
Where `ListOfLists` is a list of lists of character, either `a`,`b`,`c`, or `d`. Result must substitute `a` to `ai`, `b` to `bi`, `c` to `x`, and `d` to `y`.

For example,

```
?- to_do([[b,c],[a,d]],_,Result).
   Result = [[bi,x],[ai,y]].

?- to_do([[a,a,b],[b,c,d],[c,c,a]],_,Result).
   Result = [[ai,ai,bi],[bi,x,y],[x,x,ai]].
```

Note that Result must also be a list of lists.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is solution to your problem:

```
substitute(a, ai).
substitute(b, bi).
substitute(c, x).
substitute(d, y).
substitute(In, Out) :- maplist(substitute, In, Out).

to_do(X, _, Y) :- substitute(X, Y).
```